# Word api sending http request in IE11 DOMException Error

Tags: angular, office-js

I'm currently developing a Word Add-in using Word API for Microsoft Office Professional 2016. I am using Angular 4.

I have problem with Internet Explorer 11 when I'm trying to send a HTTP request (e.g. GET, POST). In other browsers everything works fine but in IE I get this error:

```
object DOMException] {
    ABORT_ERR: 20,
    code: 11,
    constructor: DOMException { ...
    },
    DATA_CLONE_ERR: 25,
    DOMSTRING_SIZE_ERR: 2,
    HIERARCHY_REQUEST_ERR: 3,
    INDEX_SIZE_ERR: 1,
    INUSE_ATTRIBUTE_ERR: 10,
    INVALID_ACCESS_ERR: 15,
    INVALID_CHARACTER_ERR: 5,
    INVALID_MODIFICATION_ERR: 13,
    INVALID_NODE_TYPE_ERR: 24,
    INVALID_STATE_ERR: 11,
    message: "InvalidStat...",
    name: "InvalidStat...",
    NAMESPACE_ERR: 14,
    NETWORK_ERR: 19,
    NO_DATA_ALLOWED_ERR: 6,
    NO_MODIFICATION_ALLOWED_ERR: 7,
    NOT_FOUND_ERR: 8,
    NOT_SUPPORTED_ERR: 9...
}
```

I have the same problem with Word online on Internet Explorer and Edge.  It works fine in different browsers. 
I also uninstalled Internet Explorer from Windows to "force" Word to use a different browser. However, in that case it says that the add-in cannot be run properly.

Does anybody knows how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide the code you're using to make these requests? This error is too truncated to make much sense of on it's own.

Comment: Ok, I added it:)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code I'm using:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { globalUrl } from '../../common/globalUrl';

@Injectable()
export class LoginService {
    constructor (private _http: Http) { }

    authenticate(documentDir: string,packageSize:any) {
        const headers = new Headers();
        headers.set('content-type', 'application/json');
        let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
        const body={documentDir,packageSize};
        this._http.post(globalUrl("create-document"),body,options)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .subscribe(
                (data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                (err) => {
                    console.log(err); //here appears the error 

                }
            );
    }
}
```